# rsync: list new and modified in source

Tags: rsync

I am using the following rsync command to determine all files that are newer (or different in checksum) in my source dir, or don't exist in the destination dir:

```
rsync -rltDO -hvinuczz /source/ /dest
```

and `-i` to get to know the exact reason for why a file would be transferred/updated.
I am omitting dir-times (`-O`) since there are updated directories in the destination that would show up in the output generated by rsync.
The problem I have with this command is: It lists new (i.e., not existing in the source) files in the destination like so: `>f+++++++++`.

So my questions are:

(1) Why is `-i` listing those at all? My options clearly specify that I want to sync from source to destination, all content that is newer (or has different checksum) in source. Files existing in destination but not in source do not fall into that category.

(2) Which options achieve: List anything in source that either does not exist in destination, or exists and is newer (or has diff checksum) in the source?

Note that [man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) describes `-i` like so:

> `-i`, `--itemize-changes`
>
>   Requests a simple itemized list of the changes that are being made to each file, including attribute changes. 
>     This is exactly the same as specifying
>   **--out-format='%i %n%L'**
>   . 
>     If you repeat the option, unchanged files will also be output, but only if the receiving rsync is at least version 2.6.7 (you can use
>   **-vv**
>   with older versions of rsync, but that also turns on the output of other verbose messages).
>
> The “%i” escape has a cryptic output that is 11 letters long. 
>   The general format is like the string **YXcstpoguax**, where **Y** is replaced by the type of update being done, **X** is replaced by the file-type, and the other letters represent attributes that may be output if they are being modified.
>
> The update types that replace the **Y** are as follows:
>
> - A **<** means that a file is being transferred to the remote host (sent).
> - A **>** means that a file is being transferred to the local host (received).
> - ︙

So `>f+++++++++` is telling me that there is a new file to be transferred – and if I interpret the documentation, it should be received on the local end (== source). Really?